# Merge Data from one Table into a new one in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2012

I am encountering a problem with joining a table in SQL Server. I get more rows than I need in my view.

The table I join looks something like this:

| ID | other ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Bob |
| 2 | 1 | Max |
| 3 | 2 | Jim |
| 4 | 2 | Tom |
| 5 | 2 | Ron |

The new table should look like this:

| other ID | Names |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob,Max |
| 2 | Jim,Tom,Ron |

In that way I don’t get a new row every time a new Name comes up, but it's the same "other" `ID`.

Can someone please help me solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the current query? And tag your DBMS please.

Answer (score -1):

You basically have to use a group by with some string aggregate functions

```
   Select id, string_agg(name, ',' ) from table1
   t1 Join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id group by id
```

Answer (score -1):

If your DBMS is SQL Server(2017+) or Postgres, you can use STRING_AGG aggregate function to have the names that are associated to the same id in a one row. Here is an exmple

```
SELECT other_id,
       STRING_AGG(Name, ',')
FROM table_name
GROUP BY other_id
ORDER BY other_id
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am using ms-sql 2012. I will try it out.